# Video editor with 120fps support

Tags: software-recommendation, video

I have a clips captured with GoPro3+ with the frame rate 120fps. I would like to perform some slow motion clips by stretching the video on a time-line and then in the output I want to get the file with 30fps but smoothly slowed down.
All of the editors I tried are automatically converting the 120fps file into a 25-30fps when I import it to a program and all other frame just are lost.

Please suggest any video editing software under Linux which is fully supports 60fps and 120fps video files.

Comment: I think you are better off adjusting the pts see: http://askubuntu.com/a/883010/225694

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go with `kdenlive`

```
sudo apt-get install kdenlive
```

It has most of the features like Premiere pro. Range of bitrates, frame rates and formats are supported.

Comment: ThanX a lot ) I'll try.